# Retrieving attribute values through iterations using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping an html saved on a file with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

path_xml = r"..."

content = []

with open(path_xml, "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()

content = "".join(content)
bs_content = bs(content, "html.parser")

bilder = bs_content.find_all("bilder")

def get_str_bild(match):
    test = match.findChildren("b")

    for x in range(len(test)): # here is the problem (not giving me all elements in test)
 
        return test[x].get("d")

for b in bilder:
    if b.b: 
        print(get_str_bild(b))
```

Output:

```
L3357U00_002120.jpg
L3357U00_002140.jpg
L3357U00_002160.jpg
```

Basically, there are 3 positions in the xml file where I have children of the node "*bilder*". Each block looks like this:

```
<Bilder>
    <B Nr="1" D="L3357U00_002120.jpg"/>
    <B Nr="2" D="L3357U00_002120.jpg"/>
    <B Nr="3" D="L3357U00_002120.jpg"/>
    <B Nr="4" D="L3357U00_002120.jpg"/>
    <B Nr="9" D="L3357U00_002120.jpg"/>
    <B Nr="1" D="L3357U00_002130.jpg"/>
    <B Nr="2" D="L3357U00_002130.jpg"/>
    <B Nr="3" D="L3357U00_002130.jpg"/>
    <B Nr="4" D="L3357U00_002130.jpg"/>
    <B Nr="9" D="L3357U00_002130.jpg"/>
</Bilder>
```

Currently it only returns the first picture of each block and I want to return all of them.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the cycle on bs of your bilders. You can remove your function and simplify your code as follows:

```
pic_1 = "L3357U00_002120.jpg"

bs_content = bs(content, "html.parser")
for i, builder in enumerate(bs_content.find_all("bilder")):
    print(f'builder {i}')
    for b in bilder.find_all('b'):
        if b['nr'] == pic_1:
            print(b['d'])
            #break
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that! Do you also know how to search for a specific picture and get the node or the nodes where it matches? Lets say im searching for pic_1 = "L3357U00_002120.jpg" and i want the node to get `Nr`

Comment: Same as d, you can do `b['nr']`.

Comment: Ah yes and how do i check for a match with pic_1 for instance?

Comment: There's no reference to "*pic_1*" in your post, I can't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I wrote it in my comment:
pic_1 = "L3357U00_002120.jpg", When i want to check for a match and only return those `nr` elements where it matches with pic_1. Do you know how i can do that?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Uncomment the `#break` if you want to stop at the first match for each builder.

Comment: Thank you very much again! Do you know how I can check a list of pictures instead of only pic_1? that it goes through xml for each picture in the list?

Comment: You need another cycle `for pic in pics_list:` before `if b['nr'] == pic:`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix `get_str_bild(match)` function. It currently returns the first `d` attribute.

Replace you function with this:

```
def get_str_bild(match):
    test = match.find_all("b")
    
    elements = []
    for x in range(len(test)):
        elements.append(test[x].get("d"))

    return elements
```